# Launch default Android Gallery

Tags: android, android-intent, air

I am trying to make an app that would be great if it could launch the native gallery app.  Just testing the below intent against different devices and I am getting mixed results.  Seems to fall flat on many devices by either hanging or flickering the gallery.  The app will be in adobe air so this would be bundled as a simple native extension.

adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -t image/*

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
                    Uri.parse("file://"
                            + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
            startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 0);
```

Comment: This will just open the gallery?  Seems like it is choosing an image which is not my issue.

Comment: @user1013448 What do you actually want to do? What is your purpose of accessing the gallery?

Comment: The purpose of accessing the gallery is to launch it, nothing more.  My app saves images to the SD card.  rather than build an in app gallery, user can click the gal button and it just launches the gallery.  Does not return an image.

Comment: Read the accepted ans from this link[Reusing default Android image gallery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125616/reusing-default-android-image-gallery)

Comment: So I guess the accepted answer is that it is not possible to simply launch the gallery from an app.  Seems strange.

Comment: You can use the gallery for images and videos but not the way which you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I simply used

```
            Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_PICTURE);
```